# Array Indexes incorrectly when reading input from file

Tags: arrays, c++11, indexing

I'm trying to read comma separated data from a line from a .txt file and then parse the data into 2 different arrays (names & indScores). From the indScores[], I'm getting the overall average for a particular name and storing that into my avg_scores[]. Then at the very end, return total lines that were read.

Sample input data looks like this:

```
  name1,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
  name2,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5
  name3,z1,z2,z3,z4,z5
  name4,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
  ....
```

My arrays output this

```
  names[name2, name4, name6, name8,...]
  avg_scores[x_avg, x_avg + y_avg, x_avg + y_avg + z_avg,...]
```

And my overall line count is half of what I'm expecting. Am I indexing at the wrong position or is my logic wrong?

```
int ReadScores(string fileName, string names[], float avg_scores[], int array_size){

float indScores[array_size];

int lineCounter = 0;
string myLine, nameSubString, scoreSubString;
float scoreConvert = 0.0;
float averageScores = 0.0;

ifstream myFileIn;
//open the file
myFileIn.open(fileName, ios::in);
    if (myFileIn.fail()){
        cout << "Error opening "<< fileName << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int index = 0;
    //read the file with a while loop until the end of file is reached
    while (getline(myFileIn, myLine)){
            averageScores;
            getline(myFileIn, myLine);
            //firstComma will hold the integer value of the index position of the first comma found
            int firstComma = myLine.find(',');
             //this should grab the the names at the beginning of each string on each new line
            nameSubString = myLine.substr(0, firstComma);
            names[index] = nameSubString;


            int startingPos = 0;
            float commaCounter = 0;
            //find how many commas are in a string and use that to limit your loop
            for (int ind = 0; ind < myLine.length(); ind++){
                if (myLine[ind] == ',')
                    commaCounter++;
                }

            for (int ind = 0; ind < commaCounter; ind++){
                     //grab the first number and store it the scoreSubString variable
                     //this tells the myLine.substr to start after the very first comma
                    int found = myLine.find(',', firstComma) + 1;
                    scoreSubString = myLine.substr(found, myLine.find(','));
                    //change the value of firstComma to the next index location
                    firstComma = found + 1;

                    ///convert string to number
                    stringstream(scoreSubString) >> scoreConvert;
                    ///store number in float array
                    indScores[ind] = scoreConvert;
                }

            for (int ind = 0; ind < commaCounter; ind++){
                averageScores = indScores[ind] + averageScores;
                }
                float averageOverall = averageScores/commaCounter;
                //store the averageOverall into the avg_scores []
                avg_scores[index] = averageOverall;

        index++;
        lineCounter++;
        }
    myFileIn.close();
 return lineCounter;
}
```

Comment: You call `getline(myFileIn, myLine)` twice on each iteration of the loop: once within `while`, and again two lines down. You are effectively skipping every other line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, once I deleted that second `getline(myFilenIn, myLine)` things started to match up.

I also needed to reset my `averageScores = 0` before the `for` loop that was getting my `averageScores` and add a starting position `found` for my `.find(',', found)`, without it I was constantly starting from the beginning.

My new code looks like this:

```
 int ReadScores(string fileName, string names[], float avg_scores[], int array_size){

int linesCounted = 0;
float indScores[array_size];

int lineCounter = 0;
string myLine, nameSubString, scoreSubString;
float scoreConvert = 0.0;
float averageScores = 0.0;

ifstream myFileIn;
//open the file
myFileIn.open(fileName, ios::in);
    if (myFileIn.fail()){
        cout << "Error opening "<< fileName << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int index = 0;
    //read the file until the end of file is reached
    while (getline(myFileIn, myLine)){
            //firstComma will hold the integer value of the index position of the first comma found
            int firstComma = myLine.find(',');
             //this should grab the the names at the beginning of each string on each new line
            nameSubString = myLine.substr(0, firstComma);
            names[index] = nameSubString;


            int startingPos = 0;
            float commaCounter = 0;
            //find how many commas are in a string and use that to limit your loop
            for (int ind = 0; ind < myLine.length(); ind++){
                if (myLine[ind] == ',')
                    commaCounter++;
                }

            for (int ind = 0; ind < commaCounter; ind++){
                     //grab the first number and store it the scoreSubString variable
                    int found = myLine.find(',', firstComma) + 1;
                    scoreSubString = myLine.substr(found, myLine.find(',', found));
                    //change the value of firstComma to the next index location
                    firstComma = found + 1;

                    ///convert string to number
                    stringstream(scoreSubString) >> scoreConvert;
                    ///store number in float array
                    indScores[ind] = scoreConvert;
                }

        averageScores = 0;
            for (int ind = 0; ind < commaCounter; ind++){
                averageScores = indScores[ind] + averageScores;
                }
                float averageOverall = averageScores/commaCounter;
                avg_scores[index] = averageOverall;
        index++;
        if (!myLine.empty()){
                lineCounter++;
            }
        }
    myFileIn.close();
```

return lineCounter;
}